# get_num_processes() takes no keyword arguments (CSV <-> CASSANDRA)

Tags: csv, cassandra, cqlsh

I want to export a cassandra DB to a csv file, but

cqlsh:marvel> SELECT * FROM personajes ;

```
  name       | skills
 ------------+--------
  Iron Man   | Tech  
  Spider Man | Lab
```

cqlsh:marvel> COPY personajes (name, skills) TO  'temp.csv';
**get_num_processes() takes no keyword arguments**

Tested in:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.14 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.5  | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

Thank you

Comment: Looks like it may be related to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11574

Comment: I have the same problem... created a new ticket because the old one is already resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11816

Answer (score 4):

Delete `pylib/cqlshlib/copyutil.so` and `copyutil.c` (if you have it - I didn't).

The exact path depends on your OS I guess. On Ubuntu 14.04 `copyutil.so` would be a symlink inside `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cqlshlib`.

Just delete or rename it and you should be good to go. Worked for me at least.

For reference: This is indeed a bug and the same bug as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11574, which I've learned after opening https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11816. Turned out the fix-version in the first ticket was wrong for Cassandra 2.2