# CQLSH COPY command failed : get_num_processes() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cqlsh

I am working on a Cassandra database, where I have to recreate a keyspace, and redirect data in the table of that keyspace. I successfully create the keyspace, but when I want to redirect the data :

```
copy table_name from './file_name.csv' with header=false;
```

I get this error :

> get_num_processes() takes no keyword arguments

I tried to delete the copyutil.so file, like it was suggested in the question :
[get_num_processes() takes no keyword arguments (CSV <-> CASSANDRA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077446/get-num-processes-takes-no-keyword-arguments-csv-cassandra)

but it didn't work...

Thank you

Comment: what version of Cassandra is used? How did you install it?

Comment: I use the version 3.5.0
I don't know how it was installed, because I arrived in the society after the creation of that  database, and I am the only developer today :/

Comment: You also need to remove the `copyutil.c` file as well - as described in that answer. But it's better to upgrade your Cassandra setup. You can find more information at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11574